# calling a function that may or may not make an http request

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i have function that looks something like this..

```
myFunction() {
  //some logic
  if (expression) {
    return value;
  }

  Observable.forkJoin(
    service.someHttpGet,
    service.anotherHttpGet
  ).subscribe((data) => {
    //some logic
    return value;
  });
}
```

notice that, if the expression is true, the function will return a value right away. otherwise, there may be some delay in the return. so when i write

```
const x=myFunction();
```

x will have data if expression is true, but will be undefined otherwise. i need to be able to call this function and await in case the result is delayed. how do i do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function return value depends on an at least one `Observable`, the return type of the function needs to be `Observable` or at least `Promise` as well. This changes the usage of the function of course, but there is no alternative to that.

[You can read more about basic JavaScript callbacks here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises).

Your code would be modified to:

```
myFunction(): Observable<any> {
  if (expression) {
    return Observable.of(value);
  }

  return Observable.forkJoin(
    service.someHttpGet,
    service.anotherHttpGet
  ).pipe(
      map(values => //here you'll modify the values and return the result)
  );
}
```

And on usage:

```
myFunction().subscribe(val => x = val);
```

Comment: keep in mind that i need to subscribe to the forkjoin in order to add some logic before determining a return value. if i write return Obeservable.forkJoin().subscribe() i get the following error: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Type>'. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'

Comment: Yep, that is right. If you need to modify the value, you should use the `map` operator with a pipe. I'll add it to the post.